Spring Boot: Bean configuration without ComponentScan
Currently, I'm setting bean configuration using @ComponentScan annotation:
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.storage.application", includeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = PushDocumentMapper.class),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = PushDocumentInputPort.class),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = PullDocumentInputPort.class),
})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.storage.infrastructure", includeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = IdentityContextMapper.class),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = PushDocumentIdentityContextOutputPort.class),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = PullDocumentIdentityContextOutputPort.class)
})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.storage.infrastructure")
@EnableScheduling
public class FrontofficeApplication {
}

I'd like to change this approach in order to:

Avoid using too much @ComponentScan annotations. Currently, I'm setting only two use cases.
Avoid excesive scanning process.

Could you get me some ideas for setting bean configuration using another approach?

If I understand correctly, you don't want to have a complete component scan, but only a small number of classes to be added to the context. To avoid too much fine-granular @ComponentScan annotations and an excessive scanning process across all classes, I have 2 ideas:

Use @Import to add a predefined list of classes to the Spring context. These classes could be @Configuration classes, which itself can be annotated with @Import. Or create custom meta-annotations like @ConfigureIdentityContext which contains the relevant annotations. No component-scan needed.
If possible, move the relevant classes into separate packages and scan only those packages.

